# How to bind effect in code in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, effect, viewstack

I want to add a component into a `Viewstack` dynamically in flex4. Like code below

```
 for(var i:int = 0; i < 3; i++)
 {
    var canvas:NavigatorContent = new NavigatorContent();
    canvas.label = "XXX";
    // here I want to add effect to canvas.
    // var effect:Fade = new Fade(canvas);
    // effect.duration = 2000;
    viewStack.addChild(canvas);
}
```

But the code in comment doesn't play the effect. How can I implement it? Does the canvas have any hideffect or showeffect to Bind？

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the NavigatorContent's `hideEffect` and `showEffect` properties.

[FlexExamples has a good example](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/02/27/setting-effects-with-actionscript-in-flex/) on how to set these properties using Actionscript.

Comment: minor detail: he's not using a Canvas, but a spark.components.NavigatorContent, which he happened to call `canvas`.  Nonetheless, the AS3 code you provided works the same since they both inherit from UIComponent.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think the problem is he is creating the Effect Object inside the function. As soon as this function is left, I think there is no reference from the canvas object to the effect object and the GarbageCollection cleans it up. Try explicitly saving a reference to the effect object.